# Meaning of : " public function (int $id) :array "

Tags: php, arrays, function

I searched for a clear answer but no luck , 
as far as i can understand this piece of code :

```
public function (int $id) :array {
}
```

tells me that this function will return an array or am i wrong ? 

Also, if what am i saying is correct, does this function 
can work as kind of structured array (Json for example) and can carry
and get the values declared like :

```
$this->user[$username];

or

$this->password->hashModifier($hash);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you receive an `integer` and output an `array`

See more in deep : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: You mean output `an array`? :)

Comment: Haha it's ok, here have an upvote, because this was also helping me. Didn't knew that this exist.